# Dockerサービスの起動ができません。

Tags: docker

解決したいこと
dockerを起動しようとしているのですが、エラーが出てしまいます。
dockerのインストールは出来ているはずなのですが、なぜでしょうか？
どなたかわかる方、教えてください。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
スクショのようなエラーが出てdockerが起動できません。

Comment: エラーメッセージに書かれているコマンドを実行してエラーの詳細情報を取得して調べるか、質問記事に追記してみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: そうですね。まずはエラーメッセージーのコマンドを調べてみてエラーの原因をもう少し探ってみたいと思います。

Comment: スクリーンショットを見る限り vagrant 上で docker を起動なさっているように見えますが、それより詳しい環境の情報がよく分かりませんでした。どういう環境で動かしているのかを質問文を [edit] して追記いただけませんでしょうか。具体的には Vagrantfile が参考になるかなと考えています。また、エラーメッセージにも書かれていますが、`journalctl -xe -u docker.service` にエラーログが残っているかもしれないので、そのあたりにも情報があれば追記をお願いしたいです。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。この問題についてはエラーの詳細について確認して、解決いたしました。 nekketsuuuさんのおっしゃる通り今後質問をする時はもう少し詳細な環境なども書かせてもらおうと思いました。みなさん本当にありがとうございました。